# To delete the directory(folder) in the linux server using php code?

Tags: php

I want to delete the folder which in the linux server using php ??

Scenario::

When user uploads images , A new folder is created based on his name...when i delete the user account,his named folder should be deleted..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: recursive delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490637/php-recursive-delete)

Answer (score 1):

Use unlink and rmdir. Calling `unlink($file)` will delete the file whose filename is `$file`, however this is non recursive (it only deletes one file at a time, and won't delete a directory if it is not empty).

There are tons and tons of examples that will recursively delete a directory here : https://www.php.net/unlink