# Looking for the equivalent Windows batch commands for these Linux bash commands

Tags: windows, linux, command, shell-exec

I'm new user of this forum. i want to ask my problem. what is command in windows if i have these commands in linux ?

first command :

```
if (!is_dir('geoip')) mkdir('geoip', 0744);
shell_exec('unzip -oj GeoLiteCity.zip -d geoip/');
```

Second command :

```
shell_exec('rm -rf geoip/');
```

what are those commands in windows? thanks for the help. sorry for my english.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. PHP offers cross-OS compatible functions for [creating](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)/[removing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) folders and [unzipping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php). Use them.

Comment: Okay @Pumbaa80, thanks for your suggest. I'll keep to use that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not have a built-in command to unzip a file, although it's possible to install InfoZip which has the same command-line arguments as zip does on Linux.

The command to delete a directory in Windows is `rd /s /q geoip` but there are various ways to recursively delete a directory in PHP, the latest of which is to use the new recursive directory iterator, such as mentioned on the answers to [Recursive delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490637/).